# What does this phrase from Roger Eno's "Lost in Translation" mean?

Tags: meaning, latin-to-english-translation

They are the words to the hauntingly beautiful [title song in Roger
Eno's "Lost in Translation" CD ca. 1995](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMNjD8fxHGo):

> Discontentus Sentimentum
>   Listigatus Exocentum

Either maybe it's a joke (and the words are only pseudo-Latin, I couldn't
find any in an on-line dictionary) or maybe it's something like "I have
hundreds of complaints" (that's my guess).

Comment: (just a footnote) **Exocentum** is probably the contrary (or contradictory) of **Innocentum.**

Comment: Hi Robert – was there a reason you rolled back the edit from earlier today?

Comment: i didn't like it.  i guess that's obvious.  but i didn't like being so explicit in the title and, when i posted it, i wasn't sure that it was pseudo-Latin and i wouldn't have originally posted it if i **knew** it was pseudo-Latin.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Okay, that's fair.  It's still valuable, though, to include more details in the title, so that's it's easy to distinguish the many questions asking for translation of a short phrase.  See what you think of the edit I'm making now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be psuedo-Latin as you mentioned. The only truly real word is *sentimentum*, which means "complaint or sentiment." *Discontentus* could be an actually word, formed from the prefix *dis-* meaning "apart," and *contentus* meaning having been pulled/bent or secured/maintained (i.e. pulled apart for the former). The other two words are not Latin words that I can find. *Listigatus* is close to *litigatus* meaning "lawsuit" and *exocentum* could be a combination of *ex-* meaning out of/from and *centum* meaning "one hundred." The latter does not seem to be a real construction, even though it might appear legitimate. In conclusion, this appears to be at least partially faux Latin.

Just for fun, one might translate it as "lawsuit having been pulled apart out of one hundred complaints," and even this isn't a very proper translation.

---

If anyone does find these words, I would love to hear about about it. I used [Latin Lexicon](http://latinlexicon.org/search_latin.php), [LatDict](http://www.latin-dictionary.net/), [William Whitaker's Words](http://archives.nd.edu/words.html), and [Olivetti](http://www.online-latin-dictionary.com/latin-english-dictionary.php) for my sources.